# Where do the coefficients in the Catmull-Clark subdivision algorithm come from?

Tags: subdivision

I'm learning about subdivision surface algorithms. The "Catmull-Clark" algorithm seems to be one of the most widely-used classical algorithms.

The introduction of new face points and edges is straightforward, but I'm confused by the following formula for modifying the locations of original points

$$ \frac{F + 2R + (n-3)P}{n} $$

where:

- $P$ is the original point
- $R$ is the average of all $n$ edges midpoints touching $P$
- $F$ is the average of all $n$ face points touching $P$

I understand the result is a weighted average of three points $F$, $R$ and $P$, but where do the coefficients $1$, $2$, and $(n-3)$ come from? Why $2R$? Why not $2.01R$? Or $1R$ and $2F$?

All the introductions I've seen just present the formula without presenting a justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to add a few more details to [the paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/CS284/PAPERS/CatmullClark_SDSurf.pdf) that Stefan linked to.

First of all, the matrix $H_1$ displayed in the paper is incorrect; every element should be multiplied by a factor of $\frac{1}{8}$.

$$ H_1 = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Second, the derivation of the new face point formula for quads in the first half of the paper is confusing, so I will fill in some of the details.

The matrix $G_1 = HGH^T$ contains the 16 control points for one sub-quad of the original quad with control points $G$. The entries of $G_1$ are referred to with $q_{i,j}$. Of most interest are the elements $q_{1,1}$, $q_{1,2}$ and $q_{2,2}$, which represent control points for a corner, edge, and interior of the $4\times 4$ control point grid for the sub-quad. All the other elements have similar formulas due to the symmetry of the subdivision process.

By carrying out the matrix multiplication, we get:

$q_{2,2} = \frac{P_{1,1} +P_{3,1} +P_{3,1} +P_{3,3}}{64} + \frac{6(P_{1,2} +P_{2,1} +P_{3,2} +P_{2,3})}{64} + \frac{36P_{2,2}}{64}$

We can see from this formula that, when relocating a control point, its new location is determined by the $3\times 3$ grid of points surrounding it. Here we see that in this grid, corner points have $\frac{1}{64}$ influence, edge points have $\frac{6}{64} = \frac{3}{32}$ influence, and the center ("old") point has $\frac{36}{64} = \frac{9}{16}$ influence. These weights are consistent with the ones given at the bottom of [this blog post](http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2008/08/01/catmull-clark-subdivision-the-basics/).

With a bit of rearranging, we get:

$q_{2,2} = \frac{1}{4} \big[ \frac{1}{4}(\frac{P_{1,1} + P_{1,2} + P_{2,1} + P_{2,2}}{4} + \frac{P_{1,2} + P_{2,2} + P_{1,3} + P_{2,3}}{4} + \frac{P_{2,1} + P_{2,2} + P_{3,2} + P_{3,1}}{4} + \frac{P_{2,2} + P_{2,3} + P_{3,2} + P_{3,3}}{4}) + 2\frac{1}{4}(\frac{P_{1,2} + P_{2,2}}{2} + \frac{P_{2,1} + P_{2,2}}{2} + \frac{P_{2,3} + P_{2,2}}{2} + \frac{P_{3,2} + P_{2,2}}{2}) + P_{2,2}\big]$

The first term is merely the average of the four surrounding face points; in other words, it is $F$. The second term is the average of the four surrounding edge midpoints multiplied by $2$; in other words, it is $2R$. Finally, $P_{2,2}$ is simply the original control point $P$.

And so we see this is the same as the original formula for quads: $\frac{1}{4}(F + 2R + P)$.

The paper does not provide a derivation of the general case for an $n$-sided polygon, but it seems like a reasonable extension based on intuition.

---

As an aside, here is an explanation for the other points, and [their meanings as seen on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface):

$q_{1,1} = \frac{P_{1,1} +P_{1,2} +P_{2,1} +P_{2,2}}{4}$

This is simply the formula for adding a new control point at the center of an existing quad.

$q_{1,2} = \frac{P_{1,1} +P_{1,2} +P_{2,1} +P_{2,3}}{16} + \frac{6(P_{1,2} +P_{2,1})}{16}$

Rearranging this, we see it is just the average of the two neighbouring face points and the edge endpoints:

$q_{1,2} = \frac{1}{4}(\frac{P_{1,1} +P_{2,1} +P_{1,2} +P_{2,2}}{4} + \frac{P_{1,2} +P_{2,2} +P_{1,3} +P_{2,3}}{4} + P_{1,2} + P_{2,1})$

Answer (score 3):

The derivation is presented in the original paper that introduced CC subdivisions as a generalisation of B-Spline patches: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/CS284/PAPERS/CatmullClark_SDSurf.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling to follow the derivation somewhat. If I'm not wrong, every entry of the $H_1$ matrix should be multiplied by a factor of $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but in general [link-only answers are discouraged on StackExchange](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-should-we-deal-with-link-only-answers-here). I'm not suggesting you paste the entire derivation in, but perhaps you could summarize the key points (e.g. assumptions that lead to the specific coefficients) in your answer?